# Can we use http package in nodejs with docker

Tags: node.js, docker

1. I am researching about docker and I have code a demo nodejs with docker. I use HTTP package in nodejs instead of express, the app is built with docker, but when I go to localhost:80, the return is

   > ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

   I have code a demo with nodejs and use express, it can run, and I cannot find any example using HTTP package.
2. I do not clear what EXPOSE port in docker for, that is port call to browser or port for app?

Docker file

```
FROM node:8
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app && chown -R node:node /home/node/app
WORKDIR /home/node/app
COPY package*.json ./
USER node
RUN npm install
COPY --chown=node:node . .
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

index.js

```
const http = require('http');
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.end("Hello world \n");
});

server.listen(port, hostname,  () => {
    console.log(`server is running at abcxyz http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Have you published the port at your docker run command?

```sh
docker run -p 80:3000 ...
```

2. Your hostname if you run it without docker is localhost (127.0.0.1)
   But if you run it in docker it have to be:

```js
const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, server listens to PORT 3000 and you have exposed PORT 80 to HOST which means PORT 80 has nothing corresponding running inside docker container, you actually have to EXPOSE PORT 3000 from docker container and use that.

You can use this command to map to a port usable in host where port number before : represents port to be exposed in host and port number after : represents port in docker container that's exposed AFAIK.

```
docker run -p 80:80
```